# Wind Force Field not working in my scene

Tags: force-fields

I have tried everything in my scenes but the wind force field is not working can anyone help for my this file [flag animation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rfCTGDeGNoRnTUSJkP3I8-m8tXghpMx-)

Comment: Wind must be a large value

Comment: Welcome to bse.  Please elaborate a little on what you have tried, (chances are it's not _everything_), what references you are using, what result you are after.